# How to combine OR,LIKE,AND in sql?

Tags: sql

I'm trying to using below query but its not working, Its showing all database rows in table.

Somebody please help me to resolved my issue.

```
SELECT * 
FROM table
WHERE interests LIKE  '%example%' 
  OR category LIKE  '%example%' 
  AND id=1
```

I want to run this query but from where the id=1. But its showing all records related to this query.

Comment: `WHERE (interests LIKE '%example%' or category LIKE '%example%') AND id= '1'` should do the trick

Comment: Personally, when I need to mix ANDs and ORs, I *always* use brackets.

Answer (score 1):

You have to `()` to group expressions and then combine those results.

```
SELECT * 
FROM table
WHERE (interests LIKE  '%example%' OR category LIKE '%example%')
  AND id= '1'
```

Comment: WHERE (interests LIKE '%example%' or category LIKE '%example%') AND id= '1' 

ITS WORKING PERFECT !!!! THANK YOU ....

Answer (score 1):

Your query will be executed like this

```
WHERE `interests` LIKE  '%example%' 
  OR (`category` LIKE  '%example%' AND `id`= '1')
```

because `AND` has higher precedence than `OR`. Use Parenthesis to fix your query

```
WHERE (`interests` LIKE  '%example%' OR `category` LIKE  '%example%')
  AND `id`= '1'
```

Comment: WHERE (interests LIKE '%example%' or category LIKE '%example%') AND id= '1' 

ITS WORKING PERFECT !!!! THANK YOU ....